# Functions not importing as expected

Tags: r, roxygen2, tidyr

I have a chain of two packages. However, even though I'm importing the first one, some of the functions complain that they don't exist.

Below are the pertinent parts of the package documentation:

This is `packageA` that I'm loading, I expect it to pull in everything imported by `packageB`:

```
#' @import packageB
#' @name packageA
#' @docType package
```

This is the relevant section from the `packageB` package:

```
#' @docType package
#' @name packageB
#' @import extrafont ggplot2 knitr dplyr
#' @importFrom tidyr gather spread separate unnest
```

The problem is that when I load `packageA` my expectation is that it would also import the `tidyr` functions: `gather`,`spread`,`separate`, and `unnest` via the `@importFrom` documentation in `packageB`, but it doesn't.

So,when I load `packageA`:

```
library(packageA)
a_packageB_fun(...)
error: cannot find function 'gather'
```

But, I've called it and it IS in the namespace of `packageA`

What am I doing wrong?

Updates:

sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 15.10

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_CA.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_CA.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_CA.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_CA.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_CA.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] credobb2_1.2   surv3_1.01     dplyr_0.4.3    extrafont_0.17 ggplot2_1.0.1  knitr_1.12    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.2      tidyr_0.3.1.9000 digest_0.6.8     assertthat_0.1   MASS_7.3-43      grid_3.2.2       R6_2.1.1         plyr_1.8.3      
 [9] Rttf2pt1_1.3.3   gtable_0.1.2     DBI_0.3.1        magrittr_1.5     scales_0.3.0     stringi_1.0-1    reshape2_1.4.1   extrafontdb_1.0 
[17] proto_0.3-10     tools_3.2.2      stringr_1.0.0    munsell_0.4.2    parallel_3.2.2   colorspace_1.2-6
```

Comment: Does the `NAMESPACE` file of `packageA` have `import(packageB)` in it?

Comment: What do you mean "complain that they don't exist"? Are the functions in packageB that rely on those functions (from, e.g. extrafont) not able to  find them?

Comment: Also, after doing `library(packageA); sessionInfo()` do you see `tidyr` and `extrafont` among the packages listed among those `"loaded via a namespace"`?

Comment: I'm going to update my description, I see that the way I've presented it is unclear.

Comment: From the example you've shown, which loads packageB and calls a function that's exported by it, it looks like packageA isn't involved at all... Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, it's because I had a brain fart and miswrote the packages.

Comment: Imports are not transitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `tidyr` to the `@import` directive of `packageB`

```
#' @docType package
#' @name packageB
#' @import extrafont ggplot2 knitr tidyr dplyr
```

@importFrom only works when the package is called directly, not when the package is called through another package.